# Singleton or DRY

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, dry

Suppose you have a system that interacts with a database.  Because the system uses the database so heavily, nearly every subroutine follows this pattern:

```
foo(database, rest, of, arguments)
```

That's noticed fairly quickly, and since foo is part of a larger object, the connection variable is moved to an object variable.  Unfortunately, that means the constructor for every model object takes this argument.

So you decide to create a module that can generate a connection to the database.  Since connections to the database are expensive, the connection is cached and that cached value is returned on future calls.

What you've just created is a singleton.  This is a pattern that generally frowned upon in the development community.  Then again, DRY is a principle that is encouraged, even more so than the singleton pattern is discouraged.

So which is better?  Your options are inflating the number of arguments going into every function call (or at least the constructors), or creating a singleton.  Is there a third option I'm not seeing?

EDIT: The article arguing against singletons is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx.  I think the arguments presented there make sense, I was hoping the anti-singleton camp would have a solution to this design issue.

Comment: If you can't articulate a better reason not to use a singleton pattern than people you don't know who aren't involved in your development process making nonspecific angry noise about it, I'm not seeing why not to use it.  Design pattern analysis exists to help you get things done, not to enforce arbitrary dictates of fashionability.  (Not that you were any more specific about why DRY is recommended, but the problems it addresses are things any idiot can see are bad.)

Comment: Everyone here has a pet bunch of "rules" that should "never" be violated, and if you were to throw them all together never a line of code could be written.

Comment: Fair enough, I could have been more specific in my reasons.  I'm editing the post to include links to the reasons for each.

Answer (score 2):

DRY is way, *way* more important than "don't use singletons", if any such principle is actually articulated by anyone ever (as opposed to, say, "don't horribly misuse singletons").  Feel free to satisfy both if you can and if you like, but if you must satisfy only one, satisfy DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider a lookup or injection pattern.  Create one singleton with the connection details and then have any classes that need a connection either use a "lookup" or create a system to inject it into your classes.  If abuses either can lead to problems, but for a shared resource those approaches make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: That suggestion is very close to what I'm currently using.  The narrative is how I arrived at the design, and then somebody said "hey, that's a singleton, aren't those bad?"  Half an hour of googling and this SO question later, here we are.

Comment: Yeah, dependency injection is a fine way to avoid using a singleton in this case, given the right context.  If you have a top-level App model of some kind, you can just store your database connection as a property on that instead of as a class variable, and now everybody's happy.

Comment: Fair point, but you'd still have to pass the app model around, so we're in the same boat.

Comment: @lackita: Not necessarily; it all depends on your architecture.  Make the app in turn use DI to push a reference to itself into the models it's generating to do the actual work, and passing it around is eliminated.

Comment: Could you explain what a DI is?

Comment: It's when your code has a dependency (like your `FunBusinessLogic` class needs an `App` model to provide it with persistence layer operations) and you satisfy that dependency by dynamically setting it at runtime (e.g. in the app, `fbl = new FunBusinessLogic; fbl->setApp(this); fbl->doYourThing();`).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection for lots more.

Comment: @lackita (And by "lots more", I mean "a bunch of overwrought computer-sciencey bullshit that mostly obscures the point".)

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are considered bad when used as a way to introduce global variables into a system.

Singletons implemented as `static` variables are bad as they can't be easily mocked out for testing. Being static, they don't get injected in, which hide the dependency. The discussion you are having now was prompted by you seeing this dependency all over your code. That is great! You are listening to the code and reacting by trying to find a better design. You wouldn't have noticed the dependency proliferation if that database access was through a static entry point.

The concept of several objects using a single shared instance of a class (usually as a service) is perfectly valid design. Thought of in this way, all service objects end up being a sort of 'scoped singleton'. I.E. Within this subsystem there will only be one instance of X. Implemented correctly this is a wiring decision, not a class implementation decision. I.E. you can use any class as a singleton by only making one and passing the same instance to anyone that wants one... the class in question doesn't know it's a singleton.

I agree with you that passing the 'database' to a lot of objects is a smell. I would factor all calls to the 'database' into strongly typed Repository objects, with a clean interface on each that lets the caller ask for the set of data it wants without worrying about how that data is retrieved or converted into domain objects. I would then inject the required repository into the constructor of the class that was previously using the database, rather than pass it on each call. If you are doing 'dependency injection' you will find that the wiring code move outside your objects, into factory classes. These factories will then only inject the repositories into the classes that actually need to query the repository.

One pattern I have seen is objects getting a dependency they don't really need because they in turn pass it onto some other object they create. This is prevented by factoring out this 'factory' behaviour into it's own class.

Anyway.. the short answer is "keep digging.. work out why so many classes need database access, applying single responsibility principle and dependency injection to limit the spread".